# combinatorics, board game, moves to cover all board spaces

Tags: extremal-combinatorics

I'm sure, positive, that this is a common question and has a known answer but, I do not know how to ask the question in the right way. (If I did, I could probably work out an answer for myself)

For simplicity: We have a checkered game board of, say, $4\times 4$. Assuming one can only go left, right, up, or down, and assuming that one can not go off-board, and assuming that one can go back on one's own moves, how many possible moves/ways are there to cover the board with valid moves?

So, counting valid moves for only one go at a $4\times 4$ board we have:
\begin{matrix}
2&3&3&2 \\
3&4&4&3 \\
3&4&4&3 \\
2&3&3&2 \\
\end{matrix}
And, more to the question at hand, what is the count for an arbitrarily large $N\times M$ board?

Comment: Just for clarification: You start somewhere on the board and try to visit every field? Now you want to count how many different paths you can go to achieve this goal? And going back to fields which were already visited is a valid move? If so then there are infinitely many paths because you can go circles as long as you like in between.

Comment: Yes. I was not paying attention to that part. Not asking the question correctly. 

 So, lets say on a 4x4 grid, one wants to go from the bottom left to the upper right (not stepping on one's self) how many possible steps are there; assuming one can only go left, right, up, or down and assuming one can not go off board (not toruoidal)? I'm not looking for optimal path but, rather how many paths and how many steps? And, much more to the point, for an NxM board how to figure how many paths and how many steps?

Does that make more sense? Maybe? I hope....

Comment: It is hard to understand what you actually want. If you are looking for the shortest way from bottom left corner to upper right corner then the answer is $N+M-2$. So if you expect a proper answer you should edit your question and clarify your desire.